# number of element in Redis namespace

Tags: python, redis

I have redis like this
[image]

is there any way to count the number of elements in each namespace with python?
I found `HGETALL` and `DBSIZE` but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command "scan db_index" like "scan 0" or command "info keyspace" for all database indexes and get key count, average ttl (expiration time) and expires keys. You can also use two commands "select db_index" which db_index is 0,1,2,...,15 and the other command "dbsize" to get database key count.
The command "info" show a lot info about system specifications and redis.